# Is "what" or "whom" correct in this example?

Tags: poetry, whom, who

I'm writing a poem and the last line will be either:

> A [sailor] is not *what* I wish to be

or

> A [sailor] is not *whom* I wish to be.

(Sailor is bracketed because the actual noun is different but similar.)

Which is correct in this instance, "what" or "whom"?

Comment: Your first example with "what" is correct. The meaning is job/career-oriented rather than person-orientated.

Comment: _Who are you?_ is answered by a name. _What are you?_ is answered by a profession.